# Create a custom MS Edge shortcut

Tags: browser, shortcuts, chromium, browser-tabs, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut to Microsoft Edge (new) which will launch a specific set of URL's in tabs?

I need to have the regular Edge icon to launch the default page but have a separate shortcut which launches a set of tabs i need for work instead of always manually going to these url's every morning.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run Windows app from another program or command line without changing WindowsApps folder settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/1474824/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-app-from-another-program-or-command-line-without-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to (aka 'run'):  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application"
2. Create a shortcut to msedge.exe on your desktop.  Rename it to whatever..
3. Right click that shortcut and go to "Properties", then "Shortcut" tab.
4. In the target field, append as many url's to the end as you like separated with spaces.

Your finished target field will look something like:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" www.google.com/maps www.ebaumsworld.com`